# duplicate database name won't echo else condition

Tags: php, sql

This is my code to create a Database in `SQL` using input forms.

```
<?php  
//Connect to SQL
$conn = new mysqli('127.0.0.1','root','');
if( $conn -> connect_error ){
    echo $conn -> connect_error;
    die('Connection unsuccessful');
}
echo 'Connection sucessful';

?>

<!-- ==================================================================== -->

<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="db_name">
    <input type="submit" value="Create Database">
</form>

<?php
//Create Database
if( isset( $_POST["db_name"] ) && $DBNAME = $_POST["db_name"] )
    if( $conn -> query("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS " . $DBNAME ) === TRUE )
        echo 'Database Created Sucessfully';
    else 
        echo 'Database ' . $DBNAME . ' already exists. Please try another name'; //This line won't execute
?>
```

In case of entering a duplicate database name, I want to `echo` the last line. I don't know why it is not executing. Any help?

> **Note:** Entering a duplicate name won't create anything, the page just says "Database created succesfully"

Comment: Use proper surly braces `{}`. I think your `else` is mapped with first `if` ...

Comment: @Makesh That's not true, it's not the problem. And the else like that will always be mapped to the if just before. :)

Comment: @Djip : Thanks for the clarification :) I never used to write without curly braces [as per MISRA standards]. It will lead to many issues on production codes .

Comment: @Makesh If you don't understand to write without correctly or read the code correctly it can be really meshy for everyone, yes. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
//Create Database
if( isset( $_POST["db_name"] ) && $DBNAME = $_POST["db_name"] )
    if( $conn -> query("CREATE DATABASE " . $DBNAME ) === TRUE )
         echo 'Database Created Sucessfully';
    else
        echo 'Database ' . $DBNAME . ' already exists. Please try another name'; //This line won't execute
?>
```

This should do it, as if you're using "IF NOT EXISTS" your query will always be successfully, but if you're trying to creat a Database with a name already existing the query will fail, and not return TRUE.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$query= $conn ->query("CREATE DATABASE " . $DBNAME );

if($query){
echo 'Database Created Sucessfully';
}
else{
echo 'Database ' . $DBNAME . ' already exists. Please try another name';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL Query is: `"CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS " . $DBNAME`

What it means to the SQL engine:

- if `$DBNAME` does not exist, create it and tell the application we're done!
- if `$DBNAME` exists, don't do anything and tell the application we're done!

Because your SQL executes successfully all the time, regardless of whether the table exists of not, you never ever hit the `else` clause.

Comment: How do I check for duplicate database name? I want the page to echo error in case of duplicate name

Comment: Drop "IF NOT EXISTS", like others suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to assign value in if condition. And use this to check database already exist or not

```
<?php
    if( isset( $_POST["db_name"] )  )
        $DBNAME = $_POST["db_name"];
        if( $conn->query("CREATE DATABASE " . $DBNAME ) === TRUE )
             echo 'Database Created Successfully';
        else
            echo 'Database ' . $DBNAME . ' already exists. Please try another name'; //This line won't execute
    ?>
```

Comment: I think, he is trying to assign. Bcoz, `$DBNAME` is used in creating DB which is nothing but form value.